# Changing locale to Swedish

Tags: c++, locale

I have difficulties using setlocale in my C++ program. I have a field which is ftDateTime type and data I'm trying to put in is in fixed format.

When I manually change locale in Windows settings to ones that suits the data the program works fine. When I try to change locale using code it throws an exception that the date and time format is not valid.

```
void* ptr = setlocale(LC_ALL,"Swedish_Sweden");
```

The data is date and time preceding some irrelevant data. The swedish format is first that matches the incoming data. One entry is:

`2018-07-23 10:40:30`

Comment: Are you sure the locale is named `Swedish_Sweden` ? I thought they have shorter names like `sv_SE`

Comment: When I used `sv_SE` function returned nullptr which indicates failure. Using full name get me back some pointer.

Comment: Try it [this way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale) with both strings please.

Comment: Do focus on the *real* problem, which is "data I'm trying to put in is in fixed format".  We can't see it.

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <clocale>
#include <ctime>
#include <cwchar>

int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE.UTF-8");

    wchar_t str[100];
    std::time_t t = std::time(NULL);
    std::wcsftime(str, 100, L"%A %c", std::localtime(&t));
    std::wprintf(L"Number: %.2f\nDate: %Ls\n", 3.14, str);
}
```

Output:

```
Number: 3,14
Date: måndag mån 23 jul 2018 12:58:16
```

To know how your locales on your system look do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    std::cout << "LC_ALL: " << std::setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "LC_CTYPE: " << std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The parameter that goes into `std::setlocale` is platform dependent.  On one platform, it may be "sv_SE.UTF_8", on another it may be "sv_SE", on yet another it may be "sv-FI" (with a dash, not underscore.  And... Finland?  I don't know why.)  Some platforms may have incomplete support, causing setlocale or operations dependent therein to misbehave.  To me, this seems to be a problematic area of C++.

Comment: Well, short names give me null in return. Using long one gives back pointer but still it doesnt work.

Comment: @Wumpus Try the code below in my answer to see how your locales are defined.

Comment: Well, not in direct way. I made hard codded solution that parses that fixed time to another.

Comment: @Wumpus Did you tried my code to get your locale strings? How do they look like?

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName well, i can change it to swedish ones. When changed, locale points back to `Swedish_Sweden.850` . Currently im working on other solution which can end the problem.

Comment: @Wumpus OK, if you done it, provide it as an answer here and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem not even using setlocale because it wasnt working. I have created ftDateTime field and created TFormatSettings field which I populated with data time format. Then I was able to parse it back to local date format

```
TDateTime D;
TFormatSettings fmt;
fmt.Create();
fmt.DateSeparator = '-';
fmt.ShortDateFormat = "y/m/d";
D = StrToDate(data,fmt);

return D.DateString();
```

I wrote that I was using RAD Studio but moderator deleted it for some reason.